# How do I run a shell command with argdo in vim?

Tags: vim

I want to run `p4 edit filename` for each file open in my args list. I tried:

```
:argdo exec "p4 edit %"
```

but I get:

```
E488: Trailing characters: p4 edit %
```

for each file. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are very close to the command you need, only "!" is missing:

```
:argdo exec "!p4 edit %"
```

See "`:help :!`".

Comment: Thanks. I can't vote you up because I don't have 15 reputation...but you deserve one.